# Drag a layer using a drag helper div, and have imagemaps in layer behave as if area outside imagemap is -not there-?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable, imagemap

Items are stored with x,y coordinates. The `.items` div starts at [0,0] and is repositioned based on movement of `.dragger` (which is made draggable). Everytime the user stops dragging / releases, `.dragger` is repositioned to the center of the screen, and an AJAX request is made which places the next x/y coordinated items which are in the current viewport in the `.items` container.

That's the introduction.

Every item-type has a imagemap (default [`0,0,12,12,15,15,20,25`] style). I add an html image-map with those values to `.items` for every item that is loaded.

The problem is I want the space outside the imagemap to **behave** as if the user was hovering only the `.dragger` div. I've added CSS styles to:

- dragger (cursor:move)
- imagemaps (cursor:pointer)

When I hover my mouse just outside an imagemap (but still on the image, however it is transparent png so I 'think' i'm hovering the `.dragger` div) the cursor doesn't go from pointer to move-cursor, but from pointer to normal arrow. Only outside the image-boundaries it turns into a move-cursor. And when I try to drag (on the image, outside the imagemap), i copy/drag the item-image (browser integrated drag, not the jQuery drag used on `.dragger`).

**I need the `.dragger` helper and reposition the `.items` div based on it's movement. Is the cursor/drag behavious possible?**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="dragger"></div>
    <div class="items"><!-- dynamic content --></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173391/solve-this-imagemap-problem)

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a guess here, but could you possibly make an "inverse" version of the image map using the resulting link as a draggable trigger?  You would apply it to start the draggable helper, thereby triggering the drag by being "outside" the original image map area...