# How to configure the starting point for dragging on an imagemap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, draggable

i have the following situation (please see image below after reading the following):

1. `.dragoverlay` (**white** rectangle in image) is a (jQuery) draggable div. it's the same size as the browser viewport.
2. `.items` (small **red** square(s) in image) is an absolutely positioned div of size 0x0.
3. The **light blue** `items` squares are absolutely positioned divs with an image inside and are located ***within*** `.items`.
4. The **dark blue** polygons are imagemaps which belong to the items.

I currently have the following html:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.items {
        position:absolute;
        z-index:98;
    }

    div.dragoverlay {
        position:absolute;
        z-index:97;
        background-image:url('../img/transparentpixel.gif');
    }

    div.item {

    }
</style>

<div class="dragoverlay" style="cursor:move;"></div>
<div class="items">

     <!-- this content is variable -->

       <!-- this is one item-->
       <div id="XX" style="position:absolute;left:XXpx;top:XXpx;"><img src="XX" usemap="#mapid" /></div>
       <map name="mapid" id="mapid"><area shape="poly" style="cursor:pointer;" coords="XX" href="#" onclick="javascript:alert(\'hello\')" /></map>
     <!-- this content is variable -->

</div>
```

When the white `.dragoverlay` is dragged, the red `.items` is moved accordingly. This setup is needed.

**How can I use the light blue areas in the items (just outside every blue imagemap) as a starting point for dragging? As if the user clicks the `.dragoverlay` area...**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting a 1x1 transparent gif with the width/height of an item in the dragoverlay. I put the imagemap on this image (so that it is inside the dragoverlay) and then the expected behavior turns up.